# Synonym for "Attention Points"

Tags: translation

When writing a presentation in portuguese, my native language, I sometimes include *Pontos de Atenção* which literally translates to *Attention Points*. Those are items (points) that one must pay attention to, otherwise the project/endeavor might fail.

It's something like a risk, but much less intense than that.

So, when designing presentations, how would you call a number of items that are important to the success of whatever you're talking about but are not yet to be considered risks?

Comment: More context, in particular an example sentence where you would use the expression, would help.

Comment: Initially, I thought about the word "**required**", if they are points/steps necessary for the success of something. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "not yet to be considered risks". You initially said they have to be paid attention to, or it will fail, which seems like a risk to me. You risk not being successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say,

> **Important Considerations**
>   - Have you eaten breakfast?
>   - Have you brushed your teeth?
>   - Have you gotten dressed for the day?

Or perhaps,

> **Points of Interest**
>   - Price
>   - Quality
>   - Time-to-Market

Less formally,

> **Must Haves**
>   - Two scoops of sprinkles
>   - Chocolate
>   - Marshmallow

Or simply,

> **Requirements**
>   - Delivery by drone
>   - Lightweight
>   - Very shiny

Comment: "Important Considerations" is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

**[Key](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/key?s=ts) points** may be what you want:

> Key adj. chief; major; important; essential; fundamental; pivotal: a
>   key person in the company; key industries.

You can check this link to see if the usage is what you have in mind: [8 key points for successful project management](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/8-key-points-successful-project-management-mrudul-joshi).